# Installing CUDA on Kubuntu 15.10: "error: You are attempting to install on an unsupported configuration"

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, cuda

I tried to install CUDA on Kubuntu 15.10 x64, with two Nvidia GTX 690 cards.

On https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads, I downloaded the `cuda_7.5.18_linux.run`:

[image]

then tried to run it using `sudo sh cuda_7.5.18_linux.run`.

But I get the error message `error: You are attempting to install on an unsupported configuration`.

What could be the issue?

---

I installed Nvidia drivers using this [repo](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/12/use-nvidia-graphics-drivers-in.html):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-settings
```

I installed the Nvidia CUDA toolkit using `sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit`.

The output of `nvidia-smi` is:

```
nvidia-smi
Sun Nov 15 22:20:37 2015     
+------------------------------------------------------+                     
| NVIDIA-SMI 352.41     Driver Version: 352.41      |                    
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name     Persistence-M| Bus-Id       Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|       Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 690  Off  | 0000:04:00.0     N/A |               N/A |
| 30%   32C P8  N/A /  N/A |    8MiB /  2047MiB |   N/A     Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 690  Off  | 0000:05:00.0     N/A |               N/A |
| 30%   30C P8  N/A /  N/A |    246MiB /  2047MiB |     N/A     Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                    GPU Memory |
|  GPU      PID  Type  Process name                             Usage   |
|=============================================================================|
|   0               Not Supported                                       |
|   1               Not Supported                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The output of `nvcc --version` is:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2014 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Thu_Jul_17_21:41:27_CDT_2014
Cuda compilation tools, release 6.5, V6.5.12
```

Comment: for future reference, you don't need that ppa for nvidia-352 on 15.10 it's already available through apt-get. CUDA is available as well,

Comment: CUDA is also available, run `sudo apt-cache search CUDA | grep CUDA` for a list of available packages

Comment: @mchid Thanks, you mean the right package is `nvidia-toolkit-cuda`?

Comment: I think so, there is also libcuda1-352 which I guess will be installed automatically if needed but should also be looked at.